# how to update application in ubuntu which are already installed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I am unable to update the pycharm latest version in ubuntu it's already installed on my ubuntu machine. How can I update any application directly from a terminal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

for update only execute 
apt-get install --only-upgrade 
if you wish install execute without  --only-upgrade